# Why does not work subscribe in reactive form?

Tags: angular

From is:

```
this.filterForm = this.fb.group({
      classNumber: [null, []],
      classSuffix: [null, []],
      teacher: [null, []],
      subject: [null, []]
    });
```

I try to set value for field in constructor class:

```
this.filterForm.controls["classNumber"].setValue('r', { onlySelf: true });
```

Listener looks as:

```
 this.filterForm.controls["classNumber"].valueChanges.subscribe(
      selectedValue => {
      alert(selectedValue);
});
```

Why I dont get selected value in alert message?

Comment: Can you post your class with the above code included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this stackblitz I made for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e5nq6d

If you are setting the listener *after* changing the value, you will not see an alert message. This is because the listener does not exist yet.

### Bonus

Also note that by using the option `onlySelf: true` the filterForm.value passed to the `json` pipe will not change. It seems counter-intuitive at first, but setting the value with the `onlySelf` option as false (or undeclared) updates the template representation as expected.